# interface to accept text input for wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm making Wordpress plugin which takes image as an input. I need to give an interface to the user for adding and deleting images. which is the best option for providing this interface?

Answer (score 0):

I think `media_handle_upload()` is what you're looking for. This WordPress function handles file uploads/POST requests and creates an attachment post in the database. [Here is the full documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) in the WordPress Codex.

You could use this to create an interface that would allow the user to upload images from the front end via a form.

Here is the official example they currently give for `media_handle_upload` in the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) (re-posting it here in case the link changes in the future):

**Upload Form (example):**

```
<form id="featured_upload" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="my_image_upload" id="my_image_upload"  multiple="false" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="55" />
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'my_image_upload', 'my_image_upload_nonce' ); ?>
<input id="submit_my_image_upload" name="submit_my_image_upload" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**Save the attachment (example):**

```
<?php

// Check that the nonce is valid, and the user can edit this post.
if ( 
isset( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], $_POST['post_id'] ) 
&& wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], 'my_image_upload' )
&& current_user_can( 'edit_post', $_POST['post_id'] )
) {
// The nonce was valid and the user has the capabilities, it is safe to continue.

// These files need to be included as dependencies when on the front end.
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

// Let WordPress handle the upload.
// Remember, 'my_image_upload' is the name of our file input in our form above.
$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'my_image_upload', $_POST['post_id'] );

if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
    // There was an error uploading the image.
} else {
    // The image was uploaded successfully!
}

} else {

// The security check failed, maybe show the user an error.
}
```

To let the user **delete** uploaded images, the function `wp_delete_attachment` may be what you need for your plugin. ([Full Documentation here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment)).

This lets you delete specific media attachments by ID. Here is the example given in the Codex:

```
<?php wp_delete_attachment( 76 ); ?>
```

Depending on your needs, I would also recommend exploring the [Related "Attachments" functions in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference#Post.2C_Custom_Post_Type.2C_Page.2C_Attachment_and_Bookmarks_Functions), as you might want to use some of those in your plugin as well.